# Magento2 TypeError: cart is not a function

Tags: cart, knockoutjs, magento2.1.0

I ran into a issue where i could add products to cart and i got success message too **but the minicart is not updating with the added items**.

I got below error in console, I have upgraded the magento to 2.1.0

> TypeError: cart is not a function in knockout.js

Did anyone came across this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated the bind events in the minicart file by comparing the base codes, once after update. It worked.
Just compare the `minicart.phtml` file from theme

> app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t

with core template

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌

​In these two files class and bind events may be different in your theme, that is why it is not updating.

Comment: I have the same problem ... would you post some more details about what you have done?

Comment: Just compare the minicart.phtml file from theme (app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart) with core template (vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart), class and bind events may be different in your theme, so only it is not Updating.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with Porto theme or 3rd theme. You need one more step : replace content.html of `porto theme` with core content.html file to make it works.

Three steps which I solved this problem:

1. Replace the `minicart.phtml` file from theme
   (`app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t`)
   with core template
   (`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌​`).
2. Replace `content.html` file from your theme
   (`app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html`)
   with core template
   (`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html`)
3. Remove all **pub/static/frontend** , remove var folder. Run deploy static content again : `php magento setup:static-content:deploy`

[Result minicart after fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9zPg.png)

Answer (score 1):

The function `cart()` was replaced with `getCartParam()` in 2.1.5 version, so for example, `cart().summary_count` becomes `getCartParam('summary_count')`

Answer (score 0):

The function cart() was replaced with getCartParam(), so for example, cart().summary_count becomes getCartParam('summary_count'). You can download the files in this post http://iddema.com/porto-theme-cart-is-not-function/

Files
http://iddema.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Smartwave.zip