# Magento 2.1 Minicart Knockout TypeError

Tags: cart, magento-2.1, mini-cart, knockoutjs

I'm working on a Magento 2.1 project with the Navas theme. I can add products to the cart, but the minicart doesn't show any products.. I can only visit the cartpage by going directly to the page, a click on the minicart icon doesn't send me to the cartpage.

I struggle with the following error:

> ```
> knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding 
> "css: function (){return { empty:cart().summary_count == 0} }"
> Message: cart is not a function
> ```

I have tried the following, without success another [Magento Question in the Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125178/magento2-typeerror-cart-is-not-a-function)

I'm out of ideas, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The missing step is you need to update "content.html" in mini-cart folder as well.
I have resolved it in three steps:

1. Replace the **minicart.phtml** file from theme:

   - `app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t` with the core template at:
   - `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌​`

---

2. Replace **content.html** file from your theme:

   - `app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html`

With the core template version:

- `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html`

---

3. To make sure everyting has flushed out from the Front-end. Remove all files from:

   - `pub/static/frontend`
   - `var/cache`

Run deploy static content again: **`php magento setup:static-content:deploy`**

See Image [Result minicart after fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9zPg.png) with the above steps.

Comment: I followed above steps, my error is : https://snag.gy/zKoxYR.jpg How can i solve the issue? code -> 1) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌​\minicart.phtml -> https://justpaste.it/4hw6o  2) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html -> https://justpaste.it/3kz7i