# Magento 2 - Knockout js minicart

Tags: magento-2.1, xml, mini-cart

My current theme has a layout inside of the following:

> Theme/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Inside of this I have removed the header and rebuilt it like so:

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header main-header">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">289</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

This rebuilds my header in the layout i want, however doing this results in the following error:

```
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:getCartParam('items'),as:'item'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
Message: Cannot read property 'configurable' of undefined
    at UiClass.getItemRenderer (minicart.js:127)
    at foreach (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:93)
    at knockout.js:3889
    at Object.init (knockout.js:5023)
    at init (knockout.js:3914)
    at knockout.js:2989
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1249)
    at knockout.js:2988
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
```

Now i've tried the following:

1/ Replace the minicart.phtml file from theme (app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Ch‌​eckout\templates\car‌​t) with core template (vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart‌​).

2/ Replace content.html file from your theme (app\design\frontend\Theme_namespace\Theme_module\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html) with core template (vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html)

3/ Remove all pub/static/frontend , remove var folder. Run deploy static content again : php magento setup:static-content:deploy

from this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127911/magento-2-1-minicart-knockout-typeerror) but this doesn't fix my problem. Im not 100% sure what is causing my issue, but i know it relates to the new mini-cart block i've added into the header, as removing this means I get no error.

If anyone has any info that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though inside of your theme default.xml you are calling header.container again.

This will result in the error, you're trying to overwrite a reference block that already exsists - doubling up on the page the knockout that is being called, so what you actually need to do is the following:

add a new folder inside of your magento_theme called page_layout and copy the files from the core into there:

> 1column.xml
>
> 2columns-left.xml

Then you need to change the container for the header to be called something different, for example:

> header.container.new

inside of your default.xml like so:

Then you need to add inside of your 1column change:

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
```

to

```
<container name="header.container.new" as="header_container_new" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="page.top"/>
```

This will result in the error going and the header now working correctly.